# How to refer to an open workbook in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

```
Dim test As Range

Set test = Workbooks("MonthlyReport.xlsb").Worksheets("VC Report").Range("C1")
```

VBA shows Error 9: Subscript out of range. Why is this? What is wrong with it? The workbook MonthlyReport.xlsb is open.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine for me (Excel 2007 / Win 7).  Check the **spelling** of the workbook and worksheet. *(especially matching spaces)*

Comment: @NancySchroepfer  The workbook name should match the *caption* name on the Excel window.  Have you tried `Workbooks("MonthlyReport")` rather than `Workbooks("MonthlyReport.xlsb")`

Comment: Does it matter the MonthlyReport workbook is not activated?

Comment: @NancySchroepfer  `MonthlyReport` must be **Open** but it does not have to be the **Active** workbook.

Comment: I figured it out! The statement works if you open the workbooks in one Excel workbook. That is, you can't view both workbooks side by side and you have to go to "close" to close individual workbook. If you click the Excel icon twice to open two separate workbooks, then the statement won't work. What a subtle difference! I spent almost an hour trying to figure it out.

Comment: Thanks for your help, anyway.

Comment: @NancySchroepfer  Good job debugging the issue!